# Copy two input elements on click but ignore an individual element

Tags: reactjs

So I have this components which renders an 'individual item' which has 3 inputs fields. I have created a button at the bottom of the component which copies and adds an individual item on click. I need some help rendering the the first two inputs without the final price input on click of another button. I have the button at the bottom of the component with a `className='add-donation'`. What is the best way to go about doing this in React?

I have been toying with creating a component simply for that certain price field but have had no luck getting this to work. I have also toyed with writing a each statement checking the condition of every price input and seeing what the price is. If it is 0.00 then hide. Obviously this way I would run into some problems down the line and don't want to do it this way.

```
var AddItem = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {elements: [{name: '', quantity: '', price: ''}]};
  },
  nameChange: function(index, e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements[index].name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({elements: elements});
  },
  quantityChange: function(index, e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements[index].quantity = e.target.value;
    this.setState({elements: elements});
  },
  priceChange: function(index, e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements[index].price = e.target.value;
    this.setState({elements: elements});
  },
  createNewItem: function(e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements.push({name: '', quantity: '', price: ''});
    this.setState({elements: elements});
  },
  deleteItem: function(e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements.pop({name: '', quantity: '', price: ''});
    this.setState({elements:elements});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="item-section">
          {this.state.elements.map((element, index) =>
          <div className="individual-item" key={index}>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <label>Ticket Name</label>
                <input className="ticket-name" type="text" value={element.name} onChange={this.nameChange.bind(this, index)} />
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>Quantity Available</label>
                <input className="quantity" type="number" placeholder="100" value={element.quantity} onChange={this.quantityChange.bind(this, index)} />
              </li>
              <li>
                <label>Price</label>
                <input className="price" type="number" placeholder="25.00" value={element.price} onChange={this.priceChange.bind(this, index)} />
              </li>
              <li>
                <button type="button" className="delete-item" onClick={this.deleteTicket}><i className="fa fa-trash-o delete-item"></i></button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          )}
          <button type="button" className="add-another-item" onClick={this.createNewItem}>+ Add another ticket</button>
          <button type="button" className="add-donation" onClick={this.createDonation}>+ Add donation</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I've re-read your question 2 times and I'm still not sure what you want to do... under what circumstances do you want to hide the price input? For every item after the first one?

Comment: Also, .. `pop` doesn't take any arguments. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: good to know on the pop arguments. but yes, basically whenever the `add-donation` class button is clicked, I want to render the two input elements and no price element. With the regular `add-item` button is clicked, I want it to render all three inputs like it is currently doing now. Does that make sense? I had trouble writing out the question. but thanks in advance @azium

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new item by clicking the button, add a prop saying whether or not you want to display the extra input field.

```
<button onClick={() => this.createNewItem({ type: 'donation' }) }>+ Add donation</button>
```

Then in your function:

```
createNewItem: function(options) {
  var elements = this.state.elements;
  elements.push({name: '', quantity: '', price: '', type: options.type});
  this.setState({elements: elements});
}
```

Then in your render function, only display the input field if the type is not `donation`:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div className="item-section">
      {this.state.elements.map((element, index) =>
      <div className="individual-item" key={index}>
        <ul>
          <li>...name...</li>
          <li>...quantity...</li>

          { element.type !== 'donation' &&
          <li>...price...</li>
          }

          ... 

        </ul>
      </div>
      )}

      ...buttons..  

    </div>
  )
}
```